# Including External stylesheet in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This Is hardik vyas, new to CodeIgniter, I have basic know-how about CodeIgniter. I want to include a template into CodeIgniter, but first of all I need to include an external stylesheet in a page, But I can't, I am facing a 403 error.

Here is my code:

**Controller** `header.php`

```
<?php

class Header extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        $this->load->view('header');
    }
}
?>
```

**View** `header.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/application/views/mystyle.css"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: antiquewhite">
        <h3 style="background-color: #990000;color: #ffffff">Hello</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS** `mystyle.css`

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Please provide any simple way to do this and also please show me a simple way about how to include a template in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet(s) should not be inside of the CodeIgniter `views` folder.

You folders should look like this:

```
/index.php
/css/mystyle.css
/codeigniter/application/controllers
/codeigniter/application/models
/codeigniter/application/views // <- no CSS in here
```

So your view should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css"/>
```

---

If you want CSS in your views folder then I suggest this:

**Folder**

```
/codeigniter/application/views/css/mystyle.css
```

**Code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/codeigniter/application/views/css/mystyle.css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your CSS wherever you’d like, then target that url.

Try putting it in the folder ‘`/views/mystyle.css`’ for instance ‘/’ being the root of your site, not your CI install.

From CI, you can then call it with

```
<?= link_tag(base_url().'views/mystyle.css'); ?>
```

Comment: Questions may be slightly different but answer is same! And it is useful who is stuck with this problem. Bhargav Rao you should understand.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>views/mystyle.css"/>
```